# Timer using datetime to do something

Tags: python, selenium, time, timer

I wanted my script to do something at certain hour, minute and second

i already have a code but i need it to do what it supposed to do at certain hour, minute and second

```
    self.driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(1)
    add_to_cart_button = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("product-variation")
    add_to_cart_button.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    button = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn btn-solid-primary btn--l YtgjXY")
    button.click()
```

That is my code, can anyone help me, i need the `button.click()` to click at for example 18:01:59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, time
from time import sleep

def wait_start(runTime, action):
    startTime = time(*(map(int, runTime.split(':'))))
    while startTime > datetime.today().time():
        sleep(1)

wait_start('18:01:59', lambda: button.click())
```